# Can I sort a column of a matrix and transfer each number which is in the same row in R?

Tags: r

I have a matrix with 2 columns and 100 rows. For example lets say that in the first column I have random numbers from 1 to 100. In the second column I have random numbers from 100 to 200. If I want to sort the 1st column from lower to higher, can I transfer at the same time all the numbers in the same row?

For example in row number 40, I have: ex[40,1] <- 1 and ex[40,2]<-150.

Sort the 1st column, and in the first row I want to have:
ex[1,1]<-1 ex[1,2]<-150

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. In general you will receive more answers if you provide example data. For you example you can use the function `dput(ex)` and post the output here. This way, people already have your data and can play around to get a solution that might fit you. For this post I think its fine, since there are already answers ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `dplyr` package has a nice `arrange` function you could use like so:

```
ex <- data.frame(col1=c(2,1,3), col2=c("b","a","c")) #your data.frame

library(dplyr)
arrange(ex, col1) #sort decreasing
#OR
arrange(ex, -col1) #sort increasing
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `order` like below

```
ex[order(ex[,1]),]
```